# HightLight ListView item programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview, selection

I want to select a row of a `ListView`. I've tried everything but nothing seems to work.

- I'm in the `onCreate` method
- I populate my `ListView`
- I make `setSelection` passing the `position`
- I set setSelected(true)

The method `setSelection(index)` works but I can't select the item. How to do it? I've also tried to use `requestFocus()` but it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean `setSelection()` works but you can't select the item? Then it sounds like `setSelection()` does not work!

Comment: I mean that listview scroll to the correct row but it doesn't select/highlight the the row. How to do it?

Comment: Do you use a custom adapter for your `Listview`?

Comment: Yes I have used a custom adapter. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` needs a [selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28int%29) which is a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) with a `state_selected` drawable. Otherwise, the items will not change colour when selected.

Comment: I need more information to use your solution. Could you be more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create selector item for this you have to set this item to your listview using setSelector() call.

Create a new drawable file and use a similar code as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#BB00D5FF" android:startColor="#BB00D5FF" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="9dp" android:topRightRadius="9dp" />
    </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#BB0987CD" android:startColor="#BB0987CD" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="9dp" android:topRightRadius="9dp" />
    </shape></item>

</selector>
```

And set the above drawable to the listview using setSelector(R.drawable.bg)